# Can I have Below Log files structure using log4j?

Tags: java, date, logging, log4j, log4j2

**Expectation is to have the current log with the same name (i.e test.log)
and the archival files name should be test_(CurrentDate).log.1.**

/logs/projectlogs/test.log

/logs/projectlogs/ test_20160430.log.1

/logs/projectlogs/ test_20160430.log.2

/logs/projectlogs/ test_20160430.log.3

Using below properties file, current date is getting appended with all the files.

**log4j.properties::**

```
log4j.rootLogger= ALL, A1, file, rollingAppender
#log4j.date=contains current date
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/logs/projectlogs/test_${log4j.date}.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS zzz} %-5p[%t]  %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log4j 2 manual has many example configurations, and the section on RollingFileAppender has an example that matches your requirements:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/projectlogs/test.log"
                 filePattern="logs/projectlogs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %-5p[%t] %c{1.} %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="5" modulate="true"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

What may also be of interest to you is that Log4j-2.5 introduced a Delete action that gives users more control over what files are deleted at rollover time. See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover

Comment: Your original configuration used Log4j 1.x.  To take advantage of the Log4j 2 features you do not need to recode your application. Instead, just include the log4j-1.2-api jar. That will allow calls to the Log4j 1.2 API to be routed into Log4j 2.

Comment: @Remko Popma : This solution worked for me, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Remko Popma: just a question, can we implement this feature using log4j1.x ?

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway. Log4j1.x is End of Life since August 2015. What you CAN do is what Ralph suggested in above comment: use the log4j-1.2-api-2.x.jar together with the log4j-api-2.x.jar and the log4j-core-2.x.jar. (Be sure to remove log4j-1.2.x.jar from your classpath!) This way your application can continue to use the log4j-1.x API but under the hood use log4j 2.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is called "Size And Time Based File Naming And Triggering Policy" (SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP) and can be found in the latest release of logback package, which is at the moment 1.1.7, however, it can be found in 1.1.2 as well, which I use since it produces more predictable results without too much of asynchronous processes (even though 1.1.2 is slower).

The logback package works in similar way as log4j, but uses XML based configuration file (logback.xml) which in your case may look like one below (note **test_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.%i** -- this is your pattern).

Please note, that unfortunately, **it is not (yet) possible** to limit indexes within dates. So you can't have only 5 chunks of logs for each date -- each date will be logged entirely with log chunks indexes independent for each date. You can, however, limit total number of dates and (in 1.1.7) total size of log folder (using ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy).

Also I suggest you use chunk size of 10Mb at least (100Kb is tiny), as bigger chunks, generally speaking, easier to maintain by log lib (less CPU consumption).

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
    <property name="log.folder" value="C:/logs/projectlogs"/>
<!--  UNCOMMENT BELOW SECTION IF CONSOLE IS REQUIRED -->
<!--
  <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="CONSOLE">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>[%p] [%thread] %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
-->
  <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" name="FILE"> 
    <File>${log.folder}/test.log</File>
    <Append>true</Append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/test_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100KB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <!-- up to 10 GB max -->
            <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
             <MaxFileSize>100KB</MaxFileSize>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>

  <logger name="Main">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
  </logger>     

  <logger name="ch.qos">
    <level value="WARN"/>
  </logger>
</configuration>
```

Test Java App

```
package logtester;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class LogTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Main");
        for(int i = 1; i<=20000; i++)
            logger.info("Log message "+i);
    }
}
```

Folder structure after run:

```
 13,230 test.log
102,929 test_20160430.log.0
103,168 test_20160430.log.1
102,816 test_20160430.log.10
102,816 test_20160430.log.11
103,168 test_20160430.log.2
103,168 test_20160430.log.3
103,168 test_20160430.log.4
103,168 test_20160430.log.5
102,815 test_20160430.log.6
102,816 test_20160430.log.7
102,816 test_20160430.log.8
102,816 test_20160430.log.9
```

Hope it helps.